# Umbraco, displaying images from the media picker in child nodes

Tags: umbraco

I have a products view which should display some products. The ProductItem is a child node of Products and has a property of productImage, which is a media picker. I have two ProductItem and have assigned one image each in the media picker, but I'm having trouble rendering them on the site.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.Products>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels;
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";

    var products = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse("2740e0b9-caf3-435a-89c5-982ed890e6bd"))
        .ChildrenOfType("ProductItem")
        .Where(x => x.IsVisible())
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate);


}

@foreach (var product in products)
{
  <section class="page-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="product-item">
        <div class="product-item-title d-flex">
          <div class="bg-faded p-5 d-flex ml-auto rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-0">
              <span class="section-heading-upper">@product.Value("productSubtitle")</span>
              <span class="section-heading-lower">@product.Value("productTitle")</span>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="product-item-img mx-auto d-flex rounded img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="" alt="">
        <div class="product-item-description d-flex mr-auto">
          <div class="bg-faded p-5 rounded">
            <p class="mb-0">@product.Value("productContent")</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
}
```

I can display the other information with no issue. I've read dozens of forum threads and documentation but I can't seem to figure out a simple solution for just displaying each products image inside of my foreach loop. I'm using the latest version of Umbraco.

ProductItem:

[image]

Assigned image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forget to render it in your view. The "src"attribute is empty - see attached screenshot.

Feel free to check out the Umbraco doc on how to render an image from the Media Picker at [here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Getting-Started/Backoffice/Property-Editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/Media-Picker/)

[image]